How can I change the desktop search sort order?
Recently switched to 24.04 and whenever I search for things, it often shows the Emoji/Character picker at the top, like here when I search for "sound" to go to the sound settings, which is at the bottom.
How can I fix this or remove the Characters section from the search?


You can configure search in "Settings" - "Search". Under "Search Results", you can drag the items to change their order. In the search, results are displayed in the order of these items.
Thus, in your case, drag "Settings" to above "Characters". Note that you also can disable search sources here.
